# How to get one result out of the for statement?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Combination {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
    String input = sc.next();
    System.out.printf("You entered: %d\n", Integer.parseInt(input));
    sc.close();

    int[] arr = new int[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 97; i++) {
        int num_i = arr[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= 98; j++) {
            int num_j = arr[j];
            for (int k = j + 1; k <= 99; k++) {
                int num_k = arr[k];
                if (num_i + num_j + num_k == Integer.parseInt(input))
                    System.out.printf("(%d, %d, %d)", num_i, num_j, num_k);
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

When I get a number input, I want to make a code that represents this number as the sum of three numbers.

The code is complete, but there are several combinations. I want to print out only one combination. How can I edit it?

Answer (score 2):

**First, some important suggestions:**

1. Do not parse `input` inside the nested loop as it will hit the performance. Do it once outside the nested loops.
2. Do not close `Sacnner` for `System.in` as it also closes `System.in` and there is no way to open it again without restarting JVM. It means that if it is being used in some other part of your application, your application will crash.
3. Always follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. you could name `numJ` instead of `num_j`.

Coming back to your problem, there are many ways to solve it and I have listed below just a couple of them:

1. **Use `break <<label>>` to exit the nested loops**:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Combination {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
        String input = sc.next();
        System.out.printf("You entered: %d\n", Integer.parseInt(input));
        int num = Integer.parseInt(input);

        int[] arr = new int[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = i + 1;
        }

        start: for (int i = 0; i <= 97; i++) {
            int numI = arr[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= 98; j++) {
                int numJ = arr[j];
                for (int k = j + 1; k <= 99; k++) {
                    int numK = arr[k];
                    if (numI + numJ + numK == num) {
                        System.out.printf("(%d, %d, %d)", numI, numJ, numK);
                        break start;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a number : 123
You entered: 123
(1, 22, 100)
```

2. **Put the logic in a method and `return`**:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Combination {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
        String input = sc.next();
        System.out.printf("You entered: %d\n", Integer.parseInt(input));
        int num = Integer.parseInt(input);
        printFirstCombination(num);
    }

    static void printFirstCombination(int num) {
        int[] arr = new int[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = i + 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= 97; i++) {
            int numI = arr[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= 98; j++) {
                int numJ = arr[j];
                for (int k = j + 1; k <= 99; k++) {
                    int numK = arr[k];
                    if (numI + numJ + numK == num) {
                        System.out.printf("(%d, %d, %d)", numI, numJ, numK);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a seperate function for that and after you find a combination, print it and `return` there and then to the main function. In case you didn't find a combination you return 1 which can be handled in the main function,

```
public class Combination {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
        String input = sc.next();
        System.out.printf("You entered: %d\n", Integer.parseInt(input));
        int res = printCombination(input);
        if(res == 1) {
            // Do something 
        }
        sc.close();
    }

    private static int printCombination(String input) {
        int[] arr = new int[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = i + 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= 97; i++) {
            int num_i = arr[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= 98; j++) {
                int num_j = arr[j];
                for (int k = j + 1; k <= 99; k++) {
                    int num_k = arr[k];
                    if (num_i + num_j + num_k == Integer.parseInt(input)) {
                         System.out.printf("(%d, %d, %d)", num_i, num_j, num_k);
                         return 0;
                     }
                }
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```